# Jquery keypress, keydown, keyup, input does not suit my requirement

Tags: jquery, input, keypress, keydown, keyup

I have a requirement such that in a input text box, on each value entered a validation has to occur and after the 6th character is entered a hyphen has to get appended to the string.

The solutions which I tried and the problems I encountered are listed below:

1. keyup - It is working perfectly for detecting each character entered and appending a hyphen except that "it will send only a single key entry for a long key press". Ex: If I keep '9' pressing for a long time, the value in the text box will be '999999999999' but the keyup event is triggered only once.
2. keypress - It is working perfectly for detecting each character entered and appending a hyphen except that "the keypress event is not called on a backspace". Ex: If I enter backspace I have a functionality to validate the field again and deleting the hyphen.
3. keydown - I am not getting the exact current value on each key down. Ex: If I enter '9' in the field, in the keydown event, I am getting only '' as the current value. And I type '99', I get '9' as the field value. Because of the fact that on keydown event, the value will not get updated in the field.
4. input - Everything is working fine, except that I am not able to get the keycode inside this function. (Without which I cannot detect the backspace).

So, what should be done in order to

1. work with long key presses,
2. Backspace detection,
3. current value updated when the key is pressed,

work at the same time.

For the past few hours I keep messing by exploring a lot of things. Probably it is a simple thing, but I am not able to get the answer. Your help would be appreciated a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about `.on('change', function(){})` ?

Comment: Is delaying keydown a solution for your use case: http://jsfiddle.net/whfppw0q/ ?

Comment: Thank you @DarrenSweeney . But 'change' function is getting triggered only the input blur.

Comment: So in fact you are looking for some kind of input mask. There is many plugins available for that. I guess you should find one fitting your needs, e.g maybe this one: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Comment: Thank you @A.Wolff. This solution would help me. I will try it out and if this solution works, kudos!

Comment: Yep @A.Wolff input mask is what I am looking for. Have implemented it using keyup but it was not working for long keypress. So, I was trying out other events. Finally your fiddle helped me. Thank you. As far as plugins are concerned, I didn't use them because of the additional load they are going to cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue and fix it adding this two functions:

```
$('#YourId').keydown(function () {
  yourFunction();
}).keyup(function () {
  yourFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do it once, like the first time the 6th character is entered and not every 6 you can do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/zx7snsos/

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
    var str=$('input').val();
    if(str.length>6&&str.indexOf('-')!=6)
        str=str.slice(0,6)+'-'+str.slice(6);
    else if(str.length==6)
        str+='-';
    $('input').val(str);
});
```